# Calling jQuery after method with replaceWith

Tags: jquery

I have this code block:

```
$('#mainContent').replaceWith(ucmResponse).after(function(){alert('jym')});
```

But I am not getting the `alert`. I wanted to hide the `'#mainContent'` after the `replaceWith` method completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(ucmResponse).replaceAll('#mainContent').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mainContent').replaceWith(ucmResponse).hide();
```

Comment: hmmm... replaceWith doesn`t has callback.. that is  ucmResponse ?

Comment: It wont work - because the `#mainContent` div has been replaced ! so there is nothing to hide

Comment: or if try ... $('#mainContent').empty(); $('#mainContent').append(ucmResponse).hide();

Comment: ucmResponse it is a function or jQuery object ? in second case you can just `ucmResponse.hide()`

Comment: It is a jQuery object: $.ucm.executeService(submitData,function(ucmResponse) {$('#mainContent').replaceWith(ucmResponse);}});

Answer (score 1):

Method after is not supposed to be event:

function(index)A function that returns an HTML string, DOM element(s), or jQuery object to insert after each element in the set of matched elements. Receives the index position of the element in the set as an argument. Within the function, this refers to the current element in the set.

just place alert in each() method:

```
$('#mainContent').replaceWith(ucmResponse).each(function(){alert('jym')});
```

or just as next command:

```
$('#mainContent').replaceWith(ucmResponse);
alert('jym');
```